# Cannot execute a shell in docker

Tags: bash, docker, sh

When trying to execute a shell (to modify html files in a docker container, i get the error
`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown` this basically is the same with sh, /bin/bash or bash. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'd guess it would be good to mention I'm using [this image](https://git.ucode.space/Phil/goshorly/container_registry/1). Sorry if some containers dont have a shell or something, I'm a newbie at this. I am aware I could mount it locally, but due to me not knowing the location of the files, I'd guess that isn't an option.
Thanks for any help or ideas! :)

Comment: You are correct, that error means that the container image does not have a shell installed.   Some images include the bare minimum to stay small, at the expense of making debugging more difficult.

Comment: In any case, modifying files in a container isn't a best practice; those changes will get lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd reserve `docker exec` as an occasional (if useful) debugging tool, it's not the normal way to interact with or develop containers.

Comment: Good to know,  so the better way would regardless be to mount directorys?

Answer (score 1):

This image [is based](https://git.ucode.space/Phil/goshorly/-/blob/5428ae09fb020f6616e333f8a33629d61626fdbb/Dockerfile#L23) on `scratch` which is literally an empty zero byte image so you're right, it doesn't have a shell.

Try using alpine or something with bash instead.